# Printf function parameters

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(5 + "abhishekdas\n") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The output of the program is `hekdas` . How is it working? Shouldn't it show error? How is it possible to write something like `5 + "abhishekdas"` inside `printf` function ?

Comment: What kind of error did you expect?

Comment: @effeffe i thought that how can one add an int to a string .

Comment: "How is it possible to write something like 5 + "abhishekdas" inside printf function ?" - you take a text editor and type `printf(5 + "abhishekdas")`. Simple as that. As to why it works: addition is commutative, so `5 + "string"` is the same as `"string" + 5`, which is simple pointer arithmetic. Also, `5["foobarbaz"]` works as well, for the same reason. Duplicate hundreds of times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
5+"abhishekdas\n"  ==> "abhishekdas\n"+5 ==> &"abhishekdas\n"[5] ==> "hekdas\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

`5+"abhishekdas"`

is equivalent to `&"abhishekdas"[5]`, which is the adress of the sixth element of the array.

`"abhishekdas"` is a string literal: its type is an array type. As every array object, when evaluated in an expression it is converted to a pointer type. So `5+"abhishekdas"` is simple pointer arithmetic.